# Constructing a MySQL Connector/C++ class object after one is destroyed

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

Using MySQL Connector/C++ 8.0 I define a Database class and construct an object of that class to connect to the database. That works fine. If that object is destroyed and I try to construct another one, then it fails.

Here's the class:

```
  class Database {
    private:
      std::unique_ptr<mysqlx::Session> _session;
      std::unique_ptr<mysqlx::Table>   _table;
      std::unique_ptr<mysqlx::Schema>  _schema;
    public:
      Database( std::string host,
                int         port,
                std::string user,
                std::string pass,
                std::string schema,
                std::string table ) {
        _session = std::make_unique<mysqlx::Session> ( mysqlx::SessionOption::HOST, host,
                                                       mysqlx::SessionOption::PORT, port,
                                                       mysqlx::SessionOption::USER, user,
                                                       mysqlx::SessionOption::PWD,  pass );

        _schema  = std::make_unique<mysqlx::Schema>( *_session, schema );
        _table   = std::make_unique<mysqlx::Table>( _schema->getTable( table ) );

        void write( std::map<std::string, std::string> data );  // details not pertinent here

        // close might be overkill? shouldn't things get cleaned up when
        // the object goes out of scope and is deconstructed?
        //
        inline void close() { _session->close(); _session.reset(); _table.reset(); _schema.reset(); }
      }
  }
```

I can instantiate a Database object in a thread (only one such "database" thread can ever be started at a time, so there is never any risk of contention), such as:

```
  void SomeClass::dothread_db( host,port,... etc.. ) {
    try {
      Database::Database database(host,port,user,pass,schema,table);
      while (condition ) {
        database.write(...);
        // things can change the condition
      }

      database.close();  // is this even needed?

    } catch etc..

    return;
  }
```

I can spawn `dothread_db` once, and it connects to the database and writes to it all day long, but if the conditions are met such that it completes, and then I try to spawn another one, I will get one of two possible errors:

`CDK Error: OpenSSL: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0)`

or

`CDK Error: Bad file descriptor (generic:9)`

when it tries to construct the Database object. I see no messages in `/var/log/mysql/` logs. I added the Database::close() function only after I had this problem, in case that was somehow the problem, but using it doesn't make any (apparent) difference.

Comment: you're not specifying the constructor arguments when you create the `Database` instance, so you're using the default constructor, and it never initializes any of the member variables. So you have uninitialized variables when you call `database.close()`.

Comment: Sorry, that was an oversight in my typed example. I do construct it with the needed parameters; there is no other constructor. I have since edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: Maybe not an issue, but you should close/destroy your object in reverse order. E.g. in your case `_schema` holds the reference to `_session`, so destroying `_session` before might be UB (depending on implementation details).

Comment: It must be who spawns dothread_db() thread. I've discovered that if dothread_db is spawned from the main thread when the program starts, then it's always fine. My question says I get an error when dothread_db stops and is re-spawned, but the problem is not RE-starting it. The problem is from WHERE I start it. If I never spawn it from the main() thread but instead spawn it from another thread (e.g. a thread that listens for commands) then the Database object construction is fine, but writing to the database gives CDK Error: Bad file descriptor (generic:9), even though it's the first time.